# ajax long polling persistence connection

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter 3 by default there are `'pconnect' => TRUE,`. So opened connection remain open even execution of script end.

I want to know when an opened DB connection closes if `'pconnect' => TRUE,`. How much time the connection alive?

I have huge ajax request in my app in every second (comet) & DB queries consuming huge server resources